# How to include asp.net assets when using Team Build 2008

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am able to configure our Build Server (Team Build 2008) to build our asp.net application. I've done so via

```
<ConfigurationToBuild Include="Debug|Mixed Platforms">
    <FlavorToBuild>Debug</FlavorToBuild>
    <PlatformToBuild>Mixed Platforms</PlatformToBuild>
</ConfigurationToBuild>
```

Problem though, the asp.net assets(eg. script folders, imgs, etc.) are not copied to the deployment folder. Folder(_PublishedWebsites) only contains the binaries references of the app plus the pre-compiled web services.

Is there a way to include said folders/files to the deployment folder?

Thanks

Note: Using Website Projects (WSP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work, and factors included the way our project was checked in to our source control.

1. Since we're using WSP, the assemblies refrenced are copied to the bin folder, unfortunately devs checked everything in (including this) and TFS cannot overwrite the same files since TFS marked everyfile(not for edit) as read only. The resolution is to remove those .DLLs in the bin and just check in the .refresh files and let the compiler copy the actual .DLLS to the bin.
2. The aspnet_compiler has problems with WSP as it works well with project files(ie WAP) and that the references of physical(debug/release) of the sln file confuses it (eg ......\webappfolder). The resolution is to make(hand editing the sln file) the Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath and Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath point to ".\webappfolder\" instead of the previous so that aspnet_compiler will be able to actually go to that folder and compile.
3. Make sure in the tfsbuild.proj you have the same setting (depending on the release or debug) above